# Think I came up with a proof sketch of part of the Jordan curve theorem. Can anyone read it over and check if there are any errors?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $\gamma: S^1 \to \Bbb{R^2}$ be a Jordan curve with image $K \subset \Bbb{R}^2$, and let $\Omega = R^2/K$. I think I found an elementary topological proof sketch that $\Omega$ is disconnected, although it's probably not original. It's conditional on a couple of lemmas that I haven't gotten around to proving yet, but am quite confident in.

My first observation was the following lemma: let $A$ be the set of points in $\Omega$ containing each $a \in A$ such that $\gamma$ is nulhomotopic in $R^2 - \{a\}$. Let $B = \Omega - A$. Then both $A$ and $B$ are open.

Proof that $A$ is open: let $a \in A$, and let $h: [0, 1] \times S^1 \to \Omega-{a}$ be a homotopy from $\gamma$ to a constant map. Because $h$ is a continuous function on a compact set, it attains a minimum distance $\delta > 0$ from the point $a$. If $d(a, c) < \delta$, then $h: [0, 1] \times S^1 \to \Omega-{c}$ is a homotopy from $\gamma$ to a constant map. Therefore $c \in A$, and $A$ is open.

Proof that B is open: it's essentially the same. Let $b \in B$ and let $h:[0, 1] \times S^1 \to R^2 - \{b\}$ be a homotopy from $\gamma$ to the loop $g(t) = e^{int} + b, t \in [0, 2\pi]$, where $n$ is a nonzero integer. Once again, $h$ attains a minimum distance $\delta > 0$ from $b$. Let $\epsilon < \min (1, \delta)$. If $d(b, r) < \epsilon$ then $h$ is also a homotopy from $\gamma$ to $g$ through $\Bbb{R}^2 - r$. Note that $g$ has winding number $n$ around $r$, so $\gamma$ is not nulhomotopic in $\Bbb{R}^2 - r$, and $r \in B$ as desired.

Now to show that $\Omega$ is disconnected it is sufficient to show that both $A$ and $B$ are nonempty. Note that the homotopy $h(t, s) = (1-t)*\gamma(s)$ from $\gamma$ to the zero map has compact image, so there exists $M > 0$ such that $a \in A$ whenever $|a| > M$. Showing that $B$ is nonempty is more involved. We have to show that for some $x \in \Bbb{R}^2$, $\gamma$ is not nulhomotopic in $\Bbb{R^2} - \{x\}$.

The remainder of the proof relies on the following assumption: given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $C^1$ Jordan curve $\Gamma$ which uniformly approximates $\gamma$ within a distance of $\epsilon$. If $x$ has $d(x, K) < \epsilon$, the function $h(t, s) = (1-t)\gamma(s) + t\Gamma(s)$ is a homotopy from $\gamma$ to $\Gamma$ through $\Bbb{R}^2 - \{x\}$. I'm just going to show that there exists $x$ with  $\Gamma$ non-nulhomotopic in $\Bbb{R}^2 - \{x\}$, although I think you can easily extend the proof from there to $\gamma$.

Let $G$ be the image of $\Gamma$. Let $p \in G$ have $|p| \ge |y|$ for all $y\in G$. The tangent to $\Gamma$ at $p$ is then perpendicular to the line from $0$ to $p$. Let $R$ be the ray from $p$ going through $0$, and let $q$ be a point on $R$ such that $q$ is between $p$ and the next point where $R$ intersects $G$.  I claim that every ray starting at $q$ intersects $G$.

Proof: Let $S$ be a ray starting at $q$. If $S$ goes through $p$ it trivially intersects $G$ at $p$. If $S$ points in the same direction as the ray $R$, it must intersect $G$, or else $R$ only intersects $G$ at $p$. But $G$ lies inside the closed disc $|x| \le |p|$. If you remove $R$ from this disc you disconnect the disc into two halves. $G$ intersects both of these halves, because the tangent of $G$ at $p$ is orthogonal to $R$. Therefore removing $R$ from the plane disconnects $G$. But $R \cap G = \{p\}$. $G$ is a simple closed curve, so removing one point from it cannot disconnect it. This is a contradiction, so $R$ intersects $G$ at a point besides $p$.

Only the case where $S$ is not parallel to $R$ remains. Let $T$ be the ray from $q$ going through $p$. If $S \cap G$ is empty, then $(S \cup T) \cap G = \{p\}$. Note that $\Bbb{R}^2 - (S \cup T)$ has two connected components. Once again, $G$ intersects both components because its tangent at $p$ is orthogonal to $T$. We once again find that removing $p$ disconnects $G$, a contradiction.

Now we can show that $\Gamma$ is not nulhomotopic in $\Bbb{R}^2 - \{q\}$. Let $r = d(G, q)$. Let $R = |p|$. Let $W = \bigcup_{1 \le t \le R/r} \{tx: x \in G\}$. Then $W$ contains the circle $C$ defined by $|x-q| = R$, because $G$ intersects every ray starting from q. Indeed, it is quite easy to see that $W$ deformation retracts onto $C$ via radial projection. $W$ also deformation retracts onto $G$. Note that $\Gamma: S^1 \to G$ is not a trivial loop in $\pi_1(G)$, because it is a homeomorphism from $S^1$ to $G$. Therefore the deformation retract of $W$ onto $C$ maps $\Gamma$ to a nontrivial loop in $\pi_1(C)$. It follows that $\Gamma$ is not nulhomotopic in $\Bbb{R}^2 - \{q\}$. By the preliminary discussion $\Bbb{R}^2 - G$ is disconnected.

I'd appreciate any constructive criticism or observations. Thanks!

Comment: Could you expand on why does $q$ exist? I.e. why is there an open interval on $R$, which only intersects $G$ at $p$? I guess it follows from smoothness and injectivity, but I cannot see it immediately.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the last paragraph, at all...

Comment: @erz Assuming that $\Gamma$ is $C^1$ at $p$, and that $p = \Gamma(t)$: there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $t$ such that $\Gamma|_U$ only intersects $R$ at $p$. This is because locally, $\Gamma$ looks like a line segment perpendicular to $R$-- you can make this more rigorous but that's the gist of it. Now, $K = [0, 1] - U$ is compact, and $\Gamma|_K$ does not map onto $p$ by injectivity of $\Gamma$, so there is an open neighborhood $V$ of $p$ that $\Gamma_K$ never enters. It follows that the only time $\Gamma$ intersects $R \cap V$ is at $p$.

Comment: Also, sorry for all the errors. I wrote this up hastily at like two in the morning and it was still kind of a work in progress. Thanks for reading and I may try to fix the presentation in another post.

Comment: Ok, I think everything is correct (except of some typos or so) until the last paragraph, which I still don't understand.

Comment: @erz I rewrote the proof more clearly here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468307/i-found-a-proof-of-the-jordan-curve-theorem-for-c1-curves-can-anyone-check-c